# Getting a value for a textbox from another UIViewController textbox

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview, viewcontroller

I have a view 1 with a textbox linked with a PickerView.
I have a view 2 with a textbox.
View 1 is linked with View 2 with Modal segue.

How can I use the value from textbox.View1 for texbox.View2?

Answer (score 2):

The first view controller should implement prepareForSegue: and provide the second view controller with the values it needs:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"TheSegueThatTriggersViewController2"]) {
        ViewController2 *vc2 = (ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc2.vc2TextBox.text = self.vc1TextBox.text;
    }
}
```